# A script / class to edit doc/xls live on website

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and looking a way to enable directly editting of doc or xls files.

Is there any free library or something to make it possible? Or something like google docs

In google docs I think uploading files remotely from site is available only for paid and still not sure of editting too, never used google docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google docs has an api: you can probably embed a spreadsheet if you want.

For spreadsheets: there are tons of Ajax libraries for grid controls etc eg http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid and you can back this with PHPExcel http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel which can read and write .xls files